# Scheduling function in Kivy with Clock

Tags: python, kivy, pytube

I'm having a trouble with updating my label informing which file is being downloaded with pytube in Kivy. What I am trying to get: While function DownloadPlaylist is working, when it is downloading files the program freezes and it is unable to update label. I want to create something like time.sleep, while program after each download of a file from playlist will stop for a moment and update the label or that it will update each second. I don't know how to pass title argument to the showtitle function, as well as I have trouble with calling the function in proper spot, I don't know on which activity (here it is on_touch_down, but it is surely wrong) to call it. Here is my code and thanks for help.

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):   

    def showtitle(self, title):
        self.ids.output_label.text= "Currently downloading: " + title
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.showtitle)
        
        
    def checkbox_click(self,instance,value,mp3):
        if value == True:
            self.ids.output_label.text="You selected downloading MP3 file"
        else:
            self.ids.output_label.text="You selected downloading video file"
            
    def DownloadPlaylist(self):
        url=self.ids.url.text
        urldownload=baseurl                        
        my_playlist=Playlist(url)
        for video in my_playlist.videos:
            
            if(video.age_restricted==True):
                with open(today,"a") as f:
                    f.write(video.title)
                    f.write("\n")
                    f.close()
                pass
            
        if(self.ids.output_label.text=="You selected downloading MP3 file"):      
            for video in my_playlist.videos:              
                vid = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()                 
                out_file = vid.download(urldownload)
                base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
                new_file = base + '.mp3'
                os.rename(out_file, new_file)                                  
        else:
            for video in my_playlist.videos:
                self.ids.output_label.text=f'Currently downloading: {video.title}'
                video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(urldownload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to be sure about what is happening with so little code provided, but it sounds like your `DownloadPlaylist()` method is being run on the main thread. The GUI of a Kivy app is updated on the main thread, but it cannot update when you are using the main thread for something else. The fix is to run your `DownloadPlaylist()` on another thread (See [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#thread-objects)).

And you can pass arguments to methods in `Clock.schedule..` methods by using [partial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html?highlight=partial#functools.partial), for example:

```
Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.showtitle, new_title))
```

Comment: To be exact, I have two files, GUI.py in which I have functions and GUI.kv in which I have GUI visual code. I create all buttons in GUI.kv, so I wonder if I should create a thread in this .kv file and if so - how should I do that.

Comment: You could do that by specifying a `Thread()` command  in an `on_release:` for a `Button`. Concerning updating the `Label`, since you are using a `kv` file, you could specify the `text` of the `Label` with a reference to a `StringProperty`, like `text: app.title_string`, then the `Label` will automatically update when you update that `StringProperty`.